# Dynamic intervals in SetRepeating() method Android [Xamarin.Forms] even when app is "Breaked"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I have [recently asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59459115/dynamic-intervals-in-setrepeating-method-android-xamarin-forms) and also I have kind of "found" my solution, but.. is not the real one.

As the title says, I want to create local notifications and execute them with a dynamic interval (since `AlarmManager.SetRepeating()` method hasn't dynamic intervals for setting the notification at a dynamic interval of times).

I am using **Xamarin.Forms** but I only want to achieve this with **Android**. Also, I want to achieve this, as should be clear, even when app breaks or is permanently closed), I have made this code that does what I want (notifications with dynamic intervals) but an error is thrown when the app is permanently closed or when it breaks:
[My repo GitHub](https://github.com/AndresQuiVal/LocalNotificationsXamarin)

Comment: After I clicked the Button `Send notification`,then I closed the app, but I couldn't reproduce your problem: `but an error is thrown when the app is permanently closed`.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT wait for a bit of time until app sends the next notification and then a pop up will appear indicating that my app has stoped

Comment: Yes, I could see the first notification, but I couldn't found a pop up even if I wait a few minutes.I tested with device `Google Pixel(Android 8.1)`.

Comment: I’m in android 6.0, the “pop up” or “alert” says: “x app has stopped running” (x is refer to the app name)

Comment: I tested the app with emulator of android 6.0,it didn't show the `pop up` neither. What device did you tested with?